# R - create new column of non-zero minimum value of several columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use `tidyverse` and `dplyr` to create a new column that is the rowwise non-zero minimum of multiple other columns, or 0 if all columns are 0. A simplified example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  aa = c(0, 0, 0),
  bb = c(0, 1, 2),
  cc = c(2, 5, 3)
)
```

The new column should be 2, 1, and 2. The following code works in this case, but it is extremely slow for larger data.frames.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  select(aa, bb, cc) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do( (.) %>% as.data.frame %>% mutate(minOver0 = ifelse(sum(.)==0,0,min(.[. > 0]))) ) %>%
  ungroup
```

What can I do to speed this up?

Comment: are you open to base R solutions ? it could be faster in certain cases.

Comment: Definitely. Dplyr is preferred but any solution would be great

Comment: I am not clear about your expected output. Do you want to calculate non-zero values row wise or column wise? Also you say that new column should be 0, 1 and 2 whereas after running your code the new column is 2, 1 and 2

Comment: Row-wise. You're correct - that was a typo. Should be 2, 1, 2.

Comment: `apply(df, 1, function(x) min(x[x > 0]))`

Comment: Seems that @www's solution is the obvious base strategy. Isn't there a tidyverse::row_wise function (modulo different spelling conventions)?

Comment: @42- For rows with all 0, the output from the `apply` would be `Inf`. Those `Inf` need to be replaced with `0`. But this is probably still faster than `rowwise` and `do`.

Comment: @www Your solution worked, with a little modification to handle rows of all 0. `unname(apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(sum(x)==0,0 ,min(x[x > 0]))))`. Please write an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: don't use `sum(x) == 0` because entries like -1, +1 might add up to 0. Instead do `apply(df, 1, function(x) pmax(min(x[x > 0]), 0))`

Comment: @42- I tried `rowwise` but it was projected (according to the display bar output) to take way too long.

Comment: @www: Yet another argument for learning base R paradigms first.

Comment: @RonakShah In my case, there are no negatives, but I agree your solution is more universal

Comment: `do.call(pmin, replace(df, df==0, Inf))` as another potential starting point too... should be orders of magnitude faster than `apply(x, 1...` for larger data.

Comment: @RonakShah `apply(df, 1, function(x) pmax(min(x[x > 0]), 0))` would still lead to `Inf` for rows with all `0`.

Comment: @www oops..yeah. I wanted to avoid the `ifelse` call but I guess one way would be `apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(all(x == 0), 0, min(x[x>0])))` or @thelatemail 's suggestion is good. You could do `temp <- do.call(pmin, replace(df, df==0, Inf)); replace(temp, is.infinite(temp), 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in the comments that you don't have negative values, we can simply replace the zeros in our column by `NA`, then use `pmin` and then replace the `NA`s by zeros again. This will only work if you don't have `NA`s in the rest of your table.

I extended you data frame a bit:

```
df <- data.frame(
  aa = c(0, 0, 0,0),
  bb = c(0, 1, 2,0),
  cc = c(2, 5, 3,0),
  dd = c(0,0,0,0)
)
```

Our result should now be: c(2,1,2,0)

Using the following code, we add a column of just those values:

```
df3<-df  # copy the frame
df3[df3 == 0] <- NA # replace zeros by NA, replace by <0 if you want to ignore negative values too
# apply row-wise min function after removing NAs
df3<- df3%>% mutate(minover0= pmin(aa,bb,cc, na.rm = T)) 
df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0 # and return zeros, including the zero for the last (all-zero) row
```

I haven't checked this for speed, but I imagine this is faster than the `rowwise()` in your question.